# Using metric spring_cloud_stream_binder_kafka_offset for kafka lag

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, micrometer

I have an application consuming kafka messages for a long time without any restart.
Also I have a dash that monitors the consumer lag by the property "**spring_cloud_stream_binder_kafka_offset**".

When I had to restart it recently, I realized that some topics that I haven't sent messages for more than a month, started reporting some "strange values" on the same metric.
I ran the following command to check the lags on the topic and then I realized this topic with "strange values" the column current-offset was empty "-", but i'm sure that this messages were processed in the past.

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <server> --group group-test --describe --offsets --command-config
```

| GROUP | TOPIC | PARTITION | CURRENT-OFFSET | LOG-END-OFFSET | LAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group-test | TEST | 1 | 6468 | 6468 | 0 |
| group-test | TEST | 2 | 6396 | 6396 | 0 |
| group-test | TEST1 | 0 | - | 88 | - |
| group-test | TEST1 | 1 | - | 78 | - |

As I know, and I might be wrong, that this information about the current offset is stored inside a kafka topic.
This topic also have an expire within 7 days since nothing is consumed.

My doubt is this: As the current offset has been "cleand up", shouldnt the property "**spring_cloud_stream_binder_kafka_offset**" reflects somehow this? Because its leading to some misunderstanding about the metric, since I don't have this lag.

**** **UPDATE** ****

Described a little more about the situation.

When the MS started again, and the name of the consumer is the same, its not processing this messages that its understanding as lag.
What I mean, the MS is up and running, with the same consumer name, the topic is configured to be monitored and nothing is consumed. I have other topics inside this same MS that are processing correctly.
An extra point, is that I use the confluent cloud to check this lag and there the information show no lag, as I expected.

What I realized is that for some specific partition that received another message, the currently offset gets its value updated with the LOG-END-OFFSET and everything works fine.

My doubt is really about how this metric works with this situation, it seems to loose its reference and shows everything is lag.

Answer (score 0):

See `offset.retention.minutes`. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_offsets.retention.minutes

It is 7 days by default, meaning the offsets are retained for 7 days after the last consumer left the group (with recent broker versions - since 2.1 if I recall correctly).

When the offsets are removed, it is as if the group never consumed anything from the topic/partition and, if started again, it will receive all the records in the topic/partition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gary Russel, but in this case I might be losing some importante information that is leading me to some different behaviour. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: I have tried many ways to reproduce your situation - but when a group is expired on one topic, that topic is completely removed from the `--describe` output. However, it's generally not good practice to put multiple consumers (on different topics) in the same group - otherwise a rebalance on one topic will cause a rebalance for all such consumers.